# Find integers $0 < v < u$ that are coprime, yet the Pythagorean triple $(u^2-v^2, 2uv, v^2 + u^2)$ is not primitive

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples, coprime

Find integers $0 < u < v$ that do not have a common factor, yet the pythagoran triple $(u^2-v^2, 2uv, v^2 + u^2)$ is not primitive.

Before any major assistance I am just trying to understand the question. Is it saying that even though $u$ and $v$ do not have a common factor, if put into the "formulas" for a Pythagorean triple then they would end up having a common factor thus making the Pythagorean triple not primitive?

Comment: try some $u,v$ pairs with very small numbers

Comment: I hope you mean $0<v<u$, since otherwise $u^2-v^2$ becomes negative.

Comment: The question asks you to find $u,v$ such that $u$ and $v$ do not have a common factor (this is written as $\text{GCD}(u,v)=1$), but the three numbers $u^2-v^2, 2 u v$ and $u^2 + v^2$ share a common factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple example, pick $u = 3$ and $v = 1$, clearly these do not have a common factor. Then we have that

\begin{align}
    2uv &= 2\cdot3\cdot1 = 6\\
    u^2 - v^2 &= 3^2 - 1^2 = 8\\
    u^2 + v^2 &= 3^2 + 1^2 = 10
\end{align}
which is a scalar of the well-known $3$-$4$-$5$ primitive triangle.